# composer create-project from private repo

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have a private project hosted on Bit Bucket. I have an SSH key setup. Is there a way I can use the `php composer create-project vendor/name path` command in the same way as If it was on Packagist?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well there are different ways to accomplish this one being the use of a composer repository that is used instead of packagist.org, which is a better more centralized way to manage your private composer packages. The other method is to use a composer.json that incorporates your private repos within your environments, per environment.

### First

[Composer allows you to use private repositories to create projects.](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project)

Like so...

```
composer create-project vendor/name path --repository-url=http://repo.yourcomposerrepo.com
```

Since you won't submit a private package to packagist. That url just needs a **packages.json** file at minimum, you could use [satis](https://github.com/composer/satis) or your own [packagist](https://github.com/composer/packagist) if you want a more dynamic solution to the packages.json.

The method for using composer.json applies to already created projects that will use custom repositories for private packages, not for creating new projects from private repositories. Use the next method if you want to go down a similar route.

### Second

Configure your private repository into your [config.json](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home-config-json) globally for your environment. Then like normally..

```
composer create-project vendor/name path
```

Comment: This wants a package.json and not repo.

Comment: In composer the term repository refers to satis, packagist, or other which basically just generate a package.json file. Configure the project source in the package.json and you can create project by calling on it like I did in the above example.

Comment: in a composer.json you can have a repo though ala "repositories": [ { "type" : "vcs", "url" : "git@git.blah.com:blah.git" } ] and note the key is repositories. This is how we handle our private things at my company.

Comment: Well, if you are talking about placing that repository setting within the global config.json then that would be fine. But otherwise the create-project would normally be used to create a project that doesn't exist and there would not be a composer.json as of that moment. I will add the global config.json method though. Thanks because that is another valid alternative. :)

Answer (score 17):

Yes, [Composer allows you to add private projects as 'repositories'](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) to your composer.json file. So therefore you can include private projects into another project.

[It provides support for GitHub and Bitbucket](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#git-alternatives) (as well as SVN and Mercurial).

You need to modify your composer.json file to look something like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [ {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "TheShiftExchange/test",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://github.com/TheShiftExchange/test.git",
                "type": "git",
                "reference": "master"
              }
         }
    }],
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.0.*",
        "TheShiftExchange/test": "1.0.*"
    },
}
```

Comment: Note that `"type": "package"` is for packages that don't support composer (using it will impact autoloading for example) https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2

Answer (score 9):

The way I used to:

```
composer create-project vendor/name path --repository="{\"url\": \"https://bitbucket.org/user/project.git\", \"type\": \"vcs\"}" --stability=dev --remove-vcs
```

Reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#create-project

Answer (score 3):

We have Toran Proxy (https://toranproxy.com/) installed as a private packagist, and for that we are able to create projects using command below

```
composer create-project vendor/framework --repository-url=http://your-toran-repo-url/repo/private/ --stability=dev project name
```

Stability version we use if the project is not tagged or you looking for bleeding edge version.

```
--stability=dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this post has some traction, I thought I'd add another solution which I use.
Open up ~/.bash_profile

and add something like

```
function _cmsname {
    composer create-project vendor/package --repository-url=http://private.repo.url.co.uk/ --stability=dev "$1"
}
alias cmsname=_cmsname
```

and the just type `cmsname projectname` in terminal.