# How to create your own package for composer create-project

Tags: composer-php, bitbucket

Laravel uses:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

How can I make my own package so that I can use

```
composer create-project mycompany/projectx your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

Can I use bitbucket a private repository for this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as the package is available on [packagist.org](http://packagist.org/), you can use the `composer create-project` command.

If you don't want to put your package on packagist, please refer to [composer create-project from private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160115/composer-create-project-from-private-repo):

> Like so...
>
> ```
> composer create-project vendor/name path --repository-url=http://repo.yourcomposerrepo.com
> ```
>
> Since you won't submit a private package to packagist. That url just needs a packages.json file at minimum, you could use [satis](https://github.com/composer) or your own [packagist](https://github.com/composer) if you want a more dynamic solution to the packages.json.

You can also just use `git clone` and then execute `composer install` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

They is nothing special to do for you package to be installable with `composer create-project`.

Just declare you dependencies in the composer.json of your package if you have any. The command will just copy the package into the current directory, than run composer install

You can use a private repository if you use authentification over ssh, for example:

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

> See https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md

Comment: You don't have a composer.json when running `create-project`

Comment: That's not what I wanted to say, I wanted to say declare the dependencies of your package in the package's composer.json. I've updated my post for clarity